# Unable to access variable in other class for text display [Unity]

Tags: c#, methods, unity-game-engine

I have class of shelf.cs and GameManager.cs. In shelf.cs, the method displayApple will return a string. Then the GameManager will access the string and display it in Text field.

shelf.cs

```
public class shelf: MonoBehaviour
{
        //adding all the gameobjects into a list
        public List<GameObject> players;

        public string textApp ="";

        public string displayApple()
        {
            for (int i = players.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (players [i].name == "Apple") {
                    textApp = textApp + players [i].GetComponent<Apple> ().type + " " + players [i].GetComponent<Apple> ().colour + " " + players [i].GetComponent<Apple> ().weight;
                    textApp = textApp + "\n";
                }
            }
            long_apple= textApp;
            return long_apple;
        }
    }
```

then in GameManager.cs

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    Basket bask;
    public Text text_apple; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        text_apple.text = bask.displayApple; //i want to call the method of displayApple to get the string returned.
        }
}
```

The text field wont display the string and there are errors.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameManager.Start () (at Assets/scripts/GameManager.cs:12)
```

Comment: "shelf" MUST be "Shelf"

Comment: other than that? nothing is wrong?

Comment: "displayApple" must be "DisplayApple"

Comment: it still does not display the text. am i calling the method wrongly?

Comment: it would be bask.displayApple() not bask.displayApple

Comment: also add Debug.Log("Test " + bask.displayApple() );

Comment: it is null in the debuglog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never initializing the bask in `GameManager.cs`.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
Basket bask;
public Text text_apple; 

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    bask = GameObject.Find("BaskNameInHierarchy").GetComponent<Basket>()
    text_apple.text = bask.displayApple; //i want to call the method of displayApple to get the string returned.
    }
}
```

You can also make the bask public `public Basket bask;`. Then drag a GameObject into the inspector on the GameObject that the script is attached to.

Also the `Shelf` script should be called `Basket` if you're trying to reach `displayApple()`. Or the other way around: `private shelf bask`.

Comment: it work now. but i was wondering. if i uses the calling method, void Start () {long_text=_basket.DisplayApple();  Debug.Log (long_text);}, it does not have anything in console. y? if the function is void, it displays

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you did exactly as you typed it should display `long_text` if `DisplayApple()` returns something. If my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as answer, so others won't come trying to solve an already solved problem.