# Spawning a number from an arraylist, displays the one earlier

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to spawn a gameobject in Unity, where it will generate numbers.

For some,reason the prefab is generating the numbers earlier than supposed to. For example: The prefab displays "10", but the real variable is actually 24. After the "10" prefab gets destroyed, another one spawns with "24". So basically, the prefab is being 'delayed'.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class HexToBinary : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Array 1 - F
    public GameObject cvns;
    public ArrayList HexBin = new ArrayList();
    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject explosion;
    // public GameObject spwnEnemy;
    public static int rand1;
    public static int rand2;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    // public float speed;
    public Text result;
    public TextMesh question;
    public string valGroup1;
    public string valGroup2;
    public Text totalVar1Txt;
    public Text totalVar2Txt;
    //Score

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        HexBin.Add(1); // 0001
        HexBin.Add(2); // 0010
        HexBin.Add(3);
        HexBin.Add(4);
        HexBin.Add(5);
        HexBin.Add(6);
        HexBin.Add(7);
        HexBin.Add(8);
        HexBin.Add(9);
        HexBin.Add("A");
        HexBin.Add("B");
        HexBin.Add("C");
        HexBin.Add("D");
        HexBin.Add("E");
        HexBin.Add("F");
        //rand1 = Random.Range(0, HexBin.Count - 1);
        //rand2 = Random.Range(0, HexBin.Count - 1);
        randomSpawn();
        //randomizeHex();
        // randomizeSpawn();
        // spawnExplosion();
    }


    public void spawnExplosion(Vector3 b)
    {
        //x, y, z
        Instantiate(explosion, b, Quaternion.identity);
        // explosion.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 100);
        // Debug.Log(enemy.transform.position.y);
        Debug.Log("Explotion Spawn");
    }

    //public IEnumerator enemySpawnTimer()
    //{
    //    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    //    //if random matches destroy enemy
    //    //wait 5 seconds
    //    //instantiate new enemy
    // //   randomSpawn();
    //}


    public void randomizeHex()
    {
        rand1 = Random.Range(0, HexBin.Count);
        rand2 = Random.Range(0, HexBin.Count);
        Debug.Log(rand1 + "rand1");
        Debug.Log(rand2 + "rand2");
        //Debug.Log(rand1);
        //      Debug.Log(rand1);
    }

    public void randomSpawn()
    {
        Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range(1, -2), 6, 1), Quaternion.identity);
        randomizeHex();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (question.text.Contains(totalVar1Txt.text) && question.text.Contains(totalVar2Txt.text))
        {
            result.text = "OK";
        }

        switch (HexToBinary.rand1)
        {
            case 1:
                valGroup1 = "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                valGroup1 = "2";
                break;
            case 3:
                valGroup1 = "3";
                break;
            case 4:
                valGroup1 = "4";
                break;
            case 5:
                valGroup1 = "5";
                break;
            case 6:
                valGroup1 = "6";
                break;
            case 7:
                valGroup1 = "7";
                break;
            case 8:
                valGroup1 = "8";
                break;
            case 9:
                valGroup1 = "9";
                break; 
            case 10:
                valGroup1 = "A";
                break;
            case 11:
                valGroup1 = "B";
                break;
            case 12:
                valGroup1 = "C";
                break;
            case 13:
                valGroup1 = "D";
                break;
            case 14:
                valGroup1 = "E";
                break;
            case 15:
                valGroup1 = "F";
                break;
        }
        switch (HexToBinary.rand2)
        {
            case 1:
                valGroup2 = "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                valGroup2 = "2";
                break;
            case 3:
                valGroup2 = "3";
                break;
            case 4:
                valGroup2 = "4";
                break;
            case 5:
                valGroup2 = "5";
                break;
            case 6:
                valGroup2 = "6";
                break;
            case 7:
                valGroup2 = "7";
                break;
            case 8:
                valGroup2 = "8";
                break;
            case 9:
                valGroup2 = "9";
                break;
            case 10:
                valGroup2 = "A";
                break;
            case 11:
                valGroup2 = "B";
                break;
            case 12:
                valGroup2 = "C";
                break;
            case 13:
                valGroup2 = "D";
                break;
            case 14:
                valGroup2 = "E";
                break;
            case 15:
                valGroup2 = "F";
                break;
        }

        question.text = valGroup1 + " " + valGroup2;
        totalVar1Txt.text = boxesTouch.totalVarGrp1.ToString();
        totalVar2Txt.text = boxesTouch.totalVarGrp2.ToString();
        //question.text = HexToBinary.HexBin[rand2].ToString() +" "+ HexToBinary.HexBin[rand1].ToString();
        //enemy.transform.Translate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
    //spawnExplosion();
}
```

Comment: use the debugger and step thru the code .. it's obvious that you are doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Not being rude but any question should be of general interest for everyone. Not simply a request to debug your specific code.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

> ```
>    switch (HexToBinary.rand1)
>    {
>        case 1:
>            valGroup1 = "1";
>            break;
> ```

Then later in some commented code:

> ```
> HexToBinary.HexBin[rand1].ToString()
> ```

The problem you have is that arrays (at least, in a large number of languages, including C#) [start at index 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Index 1 here (which you set `valGroup1` to the string `"1"` via your switch statement) is actually a value of `2`:

> ```
>    HexBin.Add(1); // <-- index 0
>    HexBin.Add(2); // <-- index 1
> ```

Of course...you're missing the value-zero anyway...so that'd fix your problem too.

As a side note, you don't need the switch statement at all (much less twice, you can encapsulate it as a function!), you can just use [`ToString("X")`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139957/1663383) instead. That'll *really* make things easier!

I also see some variables being treated as static and some not (and even the static ones are referenced with a mix of `HexToBinary.var` and just `var`), with no clear reason why. If you need to access these values from another script attached somewhere else in your scene [there are other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587174/unable-to-access-variable-in-other-class-for-text-display-unity).